# Is there a way to do input and output of packets in the same loop in Tornado (Python)?

Tags: python, json, io, udp, tornado

I'm working on a project there we need our Python server to take in UDP packets, process the data, then send JSON strings to our JavaScript front end. The person who has us working on this project wants us to use Tornado for websockets to send the JSON from our server to the front end.

Is there a way in Tornado to do the input and output in the same loop? More specifically, we want to get in the JSON string and then send it off to the front end in the same loop.

I'm taking over writing the Tornado stuff from someone else and I haven't used it before so any help would be appreciated!

Also, [here](https://github.com/PSASCapstone2013/rttv/blob/master/client.py) is the Python server code so far (posted 7/15/2013).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote up an example that almost exactly matches what you are trying to do [here](https://github.com/daharon/StackOverflow-Question-17534033).

In the example a TCP socket is used, but you can trivially modify it to use UDP.
Also, you probably want to use [IOStream](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/iostream.html#tornado.iostream.IOStream) instead of [SSLIOStream](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/iostream.html#tornado.iostream.SSLIOStream).

The relevant files are [consumer.py](https://github.com/daharon/StackOverflow-Question-17534033/blob/master/consumer.py) and [stream_reader.py](https://github.com/daharon/StackOverflow-Question-17534033/blob/master/lib/stream_reader.py).
You can also move the stream reader instance outside of the web socket handler and make it a global instance that is always listening, if that is your preference.